# Rails/Haml open link as 'save as'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I must serve some files for direct download by the user. But if they are some common types(like .mp3, .pdf) the client browser usually tries to show them directly. Which is not the implied behaviour. I need some helper method which will not show the files, but will open 'save as' dialogue window.

Something like

```
= link_to_save_as "Download file", @resource.url
```

Is there some ready helper method in Rails?

If there is not, is there some gem providing that functionality?

If there is not, is it possible to implement it by myself (if the browsers does not forbid this, somehow)?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at adding `send_file` to the a controller action. See [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file) here.

Probably something like:

```
def download_file(filename)
  # You obviously need some restrictions on what can be requested 

  send_file '/path/to.mp3', :disposition => 'attachment'
end
```